# Am I using Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync correctly?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am using Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync for an o365 add-in on an appointment item. I expect the handler to fire every time I adjust the time on the appointment or add/remove a participant. I am seeing the callback fire when I open the add-in, but not when I interact with the appointment.

```
initOfficeListener = () => {
  const { addHandlerAsync, start } = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  const { AppointmentTimeChanged, RecipientsChanged } = Office.EventType;

  addHandlerAsync(
    AppointmentTimeChanged,
    eventArgs => {
      start.getAsync(this.processStart);
    },
    result => console.log(result)
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you share the client build numbers you are facing this issue on? Are your handlers being initialized within the Office.Initialize method call?

Comment: Yeah `Office.initialize = this.officeInitializer;` which does some setup then calls the initOfficeListener. And I am not sure what the client build number is, these are the versions I am using in the manifest: `<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MailApp" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0">`

Comment: When you say "I expect the handler to fire every time..." do you mean the addhandlerAsync to be called everytime? Office.Initialize is only called once when the app loads the first time. When you make changes to appointment time/recipients, your callback function should be called every time, do you not see that happening? Once the events have been registered using AddHandlerAsync, they don't need to re-register on every change.

Comment: Exactly, I am not seeing the callback firing.

Comment: It does throw this error every-time it starts:
`OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: undefined, status: "failed", error: OSF.DDA.Error}`

Comment: What client are you using? Outlook Desktop? If so, could you let us know the build number for the client. You can get it from here: File->Office Account. It should be under Product Information

Comment: For now I am using o365.

Comment: Just to clarify further, are you using the rich desktop Outlook client, or are you using the web version in a browser?

Comment: Web in browser.

Comment: Appointment Time Changed is only supported in "new Outlook" Web Access: 

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Designed-to-be-fast-The-Outlook-on-the-web-user-experience-gets/ba-p/234909

Does turning "new outlook On make it work?

Comment: Hi @benhsmith13 I'm going through the same problem. I've posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145939/subscribe-to-changes-in-outlook-calendar-event-fields. I couldn't find a solution. Did you get a solution to your problem? Just to clarify, I'm using Outlook web and angular to write my addin. My requirement is to get notified of the changes being made to any fields in the ***event creation screen of calendar*** in my addin

Comment: @SebaCherian upgrade to version 1.5 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to upgrade to version 1.5 or greater.

Comment: Why is the issue caused in the first place?