# Subscribe to changes in Outlook calendar/event fields

Tags: angular, typescript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin

I followed the steps described in [Microsoft Graph Webhooks Sample for Node.js](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample) to subscribe to the changes in events, i.e. to get notified if an event is created, updated or deleted. Those are working fine.

My constant.js file is as follows

```
exports.subscriptionConfiguration = {
  changeType: 'Created,updated,deleted',
  notificationUrl: 'https://my_ngrok_id.ngrok.io/listen',
  resource: 'me/events',
  clientState: 'cLIENTsTATEfORvALIDATION'
};
```

What I really want to do is to subscribe to changes in event fields so that I can immediately update those fields in my Addin.

**Is there anyway to get notified of the changes made to fields like title, attendees, location etc in outlook event at the very instant a change is made?**

*For example, what I expect is a similar functionality of the addin [Find Time](https://findtime.microsoft.com/). In this addin you can see, if an attendee is added or removed, the attendee in the addin also gets updated right after the change is made. I want similar functionality for all the fields in event creation page. I would also like to know whether such an implementation is possible right now?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change the DefaultMinVersion to 1.7 in the manifest.xml file.

```
<Requirements>
  <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.7">
    <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
  </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Also make sure that you change to new outlook(modern). 
Then try to register events using `addHandlerAsync` within the `Office.initialize`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback
Currently it supports `Office.EventType.AppointmentTimeChanged`, `Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged`, and `Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

Notifications in Outlook/Exchange are raised on the item / items collection /  folder / folders collection / store level. Changes on the item's property level are not tracked - it is your responsibility (upon receiving an item level event) to extract the relevant (to you) fields and figure out if they have changed.

Comment: Thank you, but my requirement is to get notified the changes made to each event properties not on item level event. I have modified the question. Could you please have a look at the example I've added at the end?

Comment: In COM addins, Outlook Object Model exposes PropertyChange event, which passes the name of the changed property. That event is not available in Graph, EWS, or MAPI. It is pure Outlook UI-level event.

Comment: Seba, Can you confirm if you are writing COM or Web add-in? For Web Add-ins, there are events that can be registered for, in which case add-in(which should be running) will be triggered with events. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=office-js

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I am using Web add-in

Comment: Can someone provide an example on how to get changes made to any one field, for eg. attendees/room/title, in event creation screen of calendar? I tried listening to changes using Office.context.mailbox.item.start.getAsync function but I had to use setInterval to listen to all the changes being made and I don't think that's an efficient method. Is there any other way to subscribe to changes being made on Event creation screen on calendar other than the one I tried?

Comment: @Seba Cherian Have you tried registering events like this while initializing the office:
  
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, 
    loadNewItem, function (result) {
      if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        // Handle error.
      }
    });

Comment: @MidhunKrishna I tried to implement that. But that didn't work. I'm not getting anything inside callback. FYI I'm working on an Angular project.

Comment: Seba, Please check "addHandlerAsync" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback. Currently the supported event types are Office.EventType.AppointmentTimeChanged, Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged, and Office.EventType.RecurrenceChanged.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I tried adding that in my code. But I got an error. Could you please check the image of the code  I tried and error I got? https://imgur.com/a/1UWgCfm

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I've been trying to implement this for the last couple of days and have been stuck. I couldn't find any resources that would help me to get the solution.

Comment: @SebaCherian We checked the image code you have shared, we are not able to repro this. Minimum Mailbox requirement set for AppointmentTimeChanged is 1.7. Can you check if the requirement set is supported in your current environment or not? Refer  this- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.requirementsetsupport?view=office-js